# how does custom npm scripts works in my code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I'm reading node js code wherein package.json I found the following script

```
scripts: {
   start : 'some-dependency start' 
}
```

So, when I run `npm run start` it's actually starting my application with a web server, serving static files in my project.

My question is how `some-dependency start` running? what it can do? how it can serve my static files. I see internally `some-dependency` using `react-scripts`. But I can't wrap my head around how all these things working.

Answer (score 0):

`react-scripts` is a package that comes in built with `create-react-app` when you run `npm run start` it executes a script/program that is wrapped in react-scripts package you can see the script for start command [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js), in that you can see that the script invokes the webpack-dev-server which serves the bundled javascript on a server

Generally when you execute some script through package.json file the same happens, you need to specify a command/ invoke a script

for example consider following script present in package.json file

```
 script: {
    "development": " cd client/ && NODE_ENV=development webpack -w --config webpack.dev.config.js"
}
```

In the above example when you run `npm run development` the following things happen

1. changes the directory to client
2. Node environment is set to development
3. invokes the webpack with the config file `webpack.dev.config.js` present in the client directory

It executes what ever that is written in the config file

Feel free to ask doubts if any